# CSS Dropdown in Navbar doesn't work - Dropdown appears in navbar

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an navbar with centered li items. Two of this li items should have an dropdown while hovering over them. I tried this but the dropdown-content appears in the navbar container.
I tried this with the .dropdown and while hovering over it, the .dropdwon-content should be visible under the red border of the navbar.

My Code:

```js
function resNavBar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("idTopNav");
  var y = document.getElementById("idHomeBtn");
  var z = document.getElementById("idIconClose");
  var zz = document.getElementById("idIconMenu");
  if (x.className === "topnav" & y.className === "homebtn") {
    x.className += " responsive";
    y.className += " responsive";
    z.className = "icon-close";
    zz.className += " invisible";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
    y.className = "homebtn";
    z.className += " invisible";
    zz.className = "icon-menu";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header .topnav {
  background-color: #201D1D;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #A90101;
}

header .topnav li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header .topnav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
}

header .topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #A90101;
  color: #201D1D;
}

header .topnav .icon-home {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: #fff;
}

header .topnav .topnav a.icon-menu,
header .topnav .topnav a.icon-close {
  display: none;
}

header .topnav .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

header .topnav .dropdown .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  min-width: 10vw;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

header .topnav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

// Responsive: 
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .topnav ul li a {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon-home {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav a.icon-menu {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .topnav a.icon-close {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon-home {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .homebtn.responsive {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon-close.invisible {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon-menu.invisible {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .topnav-mid {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .topnav a.icon-close {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!---HTML:--->

<header>
  <nav class="topnav">
    <div class="homebtn" id="idHomeBtn">
      <a href="index.html" class="icon-home" onclick="none">
        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="topnav-mid">
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">link</a>
        <!--! DROPDOWN -->
        <div class="dropdown-content dropdown-content-about">
          <a href="#">link</a>

          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon-close invisible" id="idIconClose" onclick="resNavBar()">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon-menu" id="idIconMenu" onclick="resNavBar()">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>
</header>


<script src="js/responsive.js"></script>
```

Has anyone an idea why the dropdown is in the navbar?

Comment: i have included the full header css and the js script in case one of them is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown is in the navbar because you don't give it a position. Just add a top attribute to the .dropdown-content.

```
header .topnav .dropdown .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  min-width: 10vw;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  top: 100%;
}
```

And you need to get rid of the overflow on your .topnav element.